# How do I get the first word before a certain symbol

Tags: java

So, I'm trying to get the word by certain symbols. For example, say the code looks like this.

```
HelloSir#Hi  hYall#Hi
```

I want to be able to get:

```
Sir#Hi    Yall#Hi
```

I just want the specific word closest to the # symbol, so basically left and right of the symbol until the first capital letter.

I was wondering how I would do this

Comment: First step is you need to decide what a "word" is.

Comment: Take a look at regular expressions in Java, especially the Pattern and Matcher class.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a method returning an array of indices of the symbol ("#Hi").
Then I would loop through the array and add all chars to a string which are before the symbol until there is a capital char.

Like this (but I havent tested the code but hopefully the output will be "Abc"):

```
private static int getIndicesOfSymbol(String symbol) {
    //TODO
}

private static boolean isUpperCase(String s) {
    //TODO
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    String symbol = "#";
    String text = "TestAbc#Hi";
    for(int index : getIndicesOfSymbol()) {
        String word = "";
        for(int i = index-1; i >= 0 && !isUpperCase(String.valueOf(text.charAt(i))); i--) {
            text += String.valueOf(text.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```